# All Words Go to Heaven?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle, word-property

In the fantasy world of this puzzle,

- Heaven has 7 levels (1 to 7), with 7 being God's level.
- Hell has 8 levels (-1 to -8), with -8 being Satan's level.
- Purgatory (0) is somewhere in between.

**Your task:**
Use the partial lists below to **figure out how God has decided** which of the 3 places each word will go.

[image]

---

**Below I have included the same information as above, except in text form, since some people prefer that.**

### Words going to Heaven:

> <sub>(sorted by level ascending, then a-z)</sub>
>   BADGES
>   BOUNTIES
>   PROBABILITY
>   PUZZLERS
>   QUESTIONS
>   SEQUENCES
>   STACK
>   FREQUENT
>   MODERATORS
>   OVERFLOW
>   ANSWERS
>   CENSORSHIP
>   DEFINABILITY (on God's level)

---

### Words going to Hell:

> <sub>(sorted by level descending, then a-z)</sub>
>   PATTERN
>   REPUTATION
>   RIDDLES
>   THINKING
>   UNANSWERED
>   WORDPLAY
>   CALCULATION
>   ENIGMATIC
>   MATHEMATICS
>   RHYME
>   FEATURED
>   DUPLICATED
>   MICROELECTRONIC (on Satan's level)

### Words going to Purgatory:

> LATERAL
>   LOGIC
>   NEWBIES
>   PASSWORD
>   SPAMMERS
>   USERS
>   VOTES

Comment: The comments got cleared :-( I wrote a lovely little Shakespearian verse here! :'(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pattern is determined by:

> Going up or down in the alphabet, where going up is equal to $+1$, and going down is equal to $-1$, with no change being equal to $0$.

For Example:

> BADGES = B $\rightarrow$A($-1$); A$\rightarrow$D ($+1$); D$\rightarrow$G ($+1$); G$\rightarrow$E($-1$); E$\rightarrow$S($+1$): 
>  $-1 + 1 + 1 -1 + 1 = 1$

### Other Words going to Heaven

$\begin{align}
&\text{BOUNTIES} &= &+1 + 1 - 1 + 1 -1 -1 + 1 &= 1\\
&\text{PROBABILITY} &= &+1 -1 -1-1+1+1+1-1+1+1 &= 2\\
&\text{PUZZLERS} &= &+1 +1 + 0 -1 -1 +1 +1 &=2\\
&\text{QUESTIONS} &= &+1-1+1+1-1+1-1+1 &= 2\\
&\text{SEQUENCES} &= &-1+1+1-1+1-1+1+1 &= 2\\
&\text{STACK} &= &+1-1+1+1 &= 2\\
&\text{FREQUENT} &= &+1-1+1+1-1+1+1 &= 3\\
&\text{MODERATORS} &= &+1-1+1+1-1+1-1+1+1 &= 3\\
&\text{OVERFLOW} &= &+1 -1+1-1+1+1+1 &= 3\\
&\text{ANSWERS} &= &+1+1+1-1+1+1 &= 4\\
&\text{CENSORSHIP} &= &+1+1+1-1+1+1-1+1+1 &= 5\\
&\text{DEFINABILITY} &= &+1+1+1+1-1+1+1+1-1+1+1 &= 7\\
&\qquad\text{ (on God's level)}
\end{align}$

---

### Words going to Hell

\begin{align}
&\text{PATTERN} &= & -1 + 1 +0-1+1-1&= -1\\
&\text{REPUTATION} &= & -1+1+1-1-1+1-1+1-1&= -1\\
&\text{ RIDDLES} &= & -1-1+0+1-1+1&= -1\\
&\text{THINKING} &= & -1+1+1-1-1+1-1&= -1\\
&\text{UNANSWERED} &= & -1-1+1+1+1-1+1-1-1&= -1\\
&\text{WORDPLAY} &= & -1+1-1+1-1-1+1&= -1\\
&\text{CALCULATION} &= & -1+1-1+1-1-1+1-1+1-1&= -1\\
&\text{ENIGMATIC} &= & +1-1-1+1-1+1-1-1&= -2\\
&\text{MATHEMATICS} &= & -1+1-1-1+1-1+1-1-1+1&= -2\\
&\text{RHYME} &= & -1+1-1-1&= -2\\
&\text{FEATURED} &= & -1-1+1+1-1-1-1&= -3\\
&\text{DUPLICATED} &= & +1-1-1-1-1-1+1-1-1&= -5\\
&\text{MICROELECTRONIC} &= & -1-1+1-1-1+1-1-1+1-1-1-1-1-1&= -8\\
&\qquad\text{ (on Satan's level)}
\end{align}

---

### Words going to Purgatory

$\begin{align}
&\text{LATERAL} &= & -1+1-1+1-1+1 &= 0\\
&\text{LOGIC} &= & +1-1+1-1 &= 0\\
&\text{NEWBIES} &= & -1+1-1+1-1+1 &= 0\\
&\text{PASSWORD} &= & -1+1+0+1-1+1-1 &= 0\\
&\text{SPAMMERS} &= & -1-1+1+0-1+1+1 &= 0\\
&\text{USERS} &= & -1-1+1+1 &= 0\\
&\text{VOTES} &= & -1+1-1+1 &= 0\\
\end{align}$

Please check my math. There are a lot of letters here and I'm bound to have messed up somewhere.

Comment: After quickly skimming the given word placement, I like this answer. Very clever! I had noticed that most of the words in the heaven list start lower than the end and most of the words in the hell list start higher than their last, but it wasn't always the case and I couldn't figure out where magnitude came from. It's nice to see that I was on the right track. :)

Comment: I wonder if there's any level -9/8 if we use a full dictionary!

Comment: wonder what this word gets for a score: http://www.sarahmcculloch.com/luminary-uprise/2009/longest-word/

Comment: @dperry the first 32,767 characters of that word gets 132, according to my Excel function. So, if the first part is a decent representation of the whole word, then it's way above God in this puzzle universe!

Comment: @JLee : just put together a JS function, trying it out now

Comment: @JLee I get a score of 831, here's the code if interested: http://pastebin.com/St6SY4qH (word has to have at least 2 letters)

Comment: @dperry Interesting, My [Python Code](http://pastebin.com/2cf99qiz) gave me 829.

Comment: @Anachor, what's your function look like?

Comment: @dperry I did give a link. (http://pastebin.com/2cf99qiz)

Comment: @Anachor I didn't convert to lowercase, and you didn't strip spaces. so we're probably both wrong. Edit: I added a toLowerCase call, and I'm getting 829 as well

Comment: @dperry, I stripped space while copying.

Comment: I had this exact thought but I said to myself: no reason it would be limited to -8 to 7. Shoulda done it for the devil and god cases...

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7):

**Just a survey of Good and Bad words**

I experimented on a dictionary with some python code. Most of God level and Satan level words are technical jargon though. So, I chose only a few. [Here's the full list.](http://pastebin.com/nk5xsyfJ)

**God Level (Score 7)**

- `acceptability`
- `acquaintanceship`
- `biodegradability`
- `definability`

**Beyond God Level (8)**

- `acquaintanceships`
- `actinostereoscopy`
- `biopsychologist`
- `intersubstitutability`
- `psychopannychist`

**Satan Level (-8)**

- `microelectronic`
- `microspectrophotometric`
- `spectrometric`

I couldn't find any beyond satan level with a ~700,000 word dictionary.
Also as dperry pointed out [the longest technical word](http://www.sarahmcculloch.com/luminary-uprise/2009/longest-word/) has a huge score of 829.

Also of 675224 of the dictionary I used,

- 259064 are going to heaven
- 254621 are going to hell
- 161539 are going to the purgatory

Seems like a lot of confused souls. [Detailed results here](http://pastebin.com/KDykJfX5)

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but +1 anyway for a big effort and some interesting facts!